# Ruby / Rails how to split array specifying step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's assume that I have an array `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

How can I split this array to get groups with elements specified by step?

For example:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
...
output = [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Is there any built-in function or elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip).

Try following:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 3
x = input.each_slice(n).to_a # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
output = x[0].zip(*x[1..-1]).map(&:compact) # => [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use [`Array#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) here:

```
>> input.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose
IndexError: element size differs (1 should be 3)
        from (irb):15:in `transpose'
        from (irb):15
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

---

**UPDATE**: Alternative

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 3
output = (1..n).map { [] }
input.each_with_index do |x, i| output[i % n] << x end
output # => [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: What OP is looking for actually? :) I didn't get..

Comment: @ArupRakshit, OP wants something like this `xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; [xs[i::3] for i in range(3)]` (Python code) in Ruby.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, `[xs[0], xs[3], xs[6], ...], [xs[1], xs[4], xs[7], ..], [xs[2], xs[5], xs[8], ...]]`

Comment: @ArupRakshit, Maybe I misunderstood. OP accepted the answer, then unaccepted it ;)

Comment: Humm I see that. Very confusing post was posted by OP. :(

Answer (score 2):

If the values are continuous like your example, you can use `group_by` in conjunction with your step as the modulus:

```
> (1..10).group_by {|v| v % 3 }.values
=> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

If they aren't continuous, then you can still do it in a one-liner, though it's a little less elegant:

```
> (1..10).each_with_index.group_by {|v| v[1] % 3 }.map {|k,v| v.map &:first }
=> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Why you put `3`.. asking just to know your thought,

Comment: 3 is the desired step, per the OP's example.

Comment: Huum means `Range#step` can be implemented this way for Array also.. right?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Neither Array or Enumerable implements step.

Comment: I know that OP didn't put the reason for the expected output.. means question is not clear.But your code produced the output very well manner,so I am thinking where I can think of your idea,in future.. :

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as below :

```
n = 3
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a = input.each_slice(n).to_a
output = (0...n).map { |i| a.map{|e| e[i]}.compact }
# => [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Taking from the link of **@falsetru** in a method way representation :

```
def divide(input, n)
  a = input.each_slice(n).to_a
  (0...n).map { |i| a.map{|e| e[i]}.compact }
end

p divide([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3)
p divide([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 3)
p divide([1, 2, 3], 3)
# >> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
# >> [[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16], [2, 5, 8, 11, 14], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
# >> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: Try with `input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`. `a.size-1` should be replaced with `3` (or `n` if you defined it).

Comment: Now, try with `input = [1,2,3]`. ;)  BTW, Why don't just replace as I suggest?

Comment: @falsetru I didn't get your point.. could you edit on my behalf? please

Comment: I updated your code (maybe too radical)

Comment: @falsetru But where is `delete_if` ? :) That's for removing the empty array.

Comment: `delete_if` is not required. See http://ideone.com/MjaFZg

Comment: It was an coincidence. `a.size - 1 == 3`. That version only work for cases where `10 <= input.size <= 12`.

Comment: @falsetru Thank you for the edit and for making my code more rubyistic .. :)

Comment: @falsetru I think 3 should be replaced by n here `input.each_slice(3).to_a`.. right ?

Comment: You're right. It was a mistake.